# How to avoid AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'PassCheck'

Tags: python, tkinter

I have read previous posts regarding this error but could not identify what I was doing wrong. Please can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
from tkinter import *

class Passwordchecker():
    def __init__(self):
       self= Tk()
       self.geometry("200x200")
       self.title("Password checker")
       self.entry=Entry(self)
       self.entry.pack()
       self.button=Button(self,text="Enter",command= lambda: self.PassCheck(self.entry,self.label))
       self.button.pack()
       self.label=Label(self,text="Please a password")
       self.label.pack()
       self.mainloop()

    def PassCheck(self1,self2):
       password = self1.get()
       if len(password)>=9 and len(password)<=12:
          self2.config(text="Password is correct")
       else:
          self2.config(text="Password is incorrect")

run = Passwordchecker()
```

Answer (score 5):

## What triggered the error?

You get this error message:

```
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'PassCheck'
```

Because when an instance of `Passwordchecker()` is initialized, it stumbles on the `mainloop()` method of your `__init__()` which does not let your program to recognize any further method belonging to that instance. As a rule of thumb, **NEVER** run `mainloop()` inside `__init__()`. This fixes fully the error message you got above. However, we have other things to fix, and for that, let us redesign your program:

## Design

It is better to resort to an other method you call inside `__init__()` to draw your GUI. Let us call it `initialize_user_interface()`.

When it comes to `PassCheck()`, you need first to past the object itself to this method. This means the first argument to pass to this method is `self`. And that is the only argument we need in fact `PassCheck(self)` because you can access from this method the remaining argument you passed uselessly to it.

## Program

So here is the full program you need:

```
import tkinter as tk
class Passwordchecker(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
       self.parent = parent
       self.initialize_user_interface()

   def initialize_user_interface(self):
       self.parent.geometry("200x200")
       self.parent.title("Password checker")
       self.entry=tk.Entry(self.parent)
       self.entry.pack()
       self.button=tk.Button(self.parent,text="Enter", command=self.PassCheck)
       self.button.pack()
       self.label=tk.Label(self.parent,text="Please a password")
       self.label.pack()

   def PassCheck(self):
       password = self.entry.get()
       if len(password)>=9 and len(password)<=12:
          self.label.config(text="Password is correct")
       else:
          self.label.config(text="Password is incorrect")

if __name__ == '__main__':

   root = tk.Tk()
   run = Passwordchecker(root)
   root.mainloop()
```

## Demo

Here is a screenshot of the running program:

[image]